# Architecture advice needed for WCF services

Tags: wcf, connection-string, claims-based-identity, multiple-databases, wcf-authentication

I'm currently working on a backend infrastructure and I could need some advice.

First, here is the current global architecture:

- I have WCF services hosted in IIS
- I have multiples databases hosted on SQL Server. One `ClientData` database per client and one global `MasterDatabase`.
- `MasterDatabase` contains a mapping of credentials associated to a connection string. That database allows me to use the appropriate `ClientData` database (via Entity Framework) depending on the credentials provided.
- I'm using Basic Auth over SSL.
- Credentials verification are done in overridden method `checkAccessCore()` in my `ServiceAuthorizationManager` subclass. Inside that method, I fetch `MasterDatabase`, ensure credentials are correct (password are saved in DB using Bcrypt) and retrieve the connection string.
- Once the connection string is retrieved, I create an instance of my class `CustomIdentity` that inherits from `GenericIdentity`. Using that instance I can then set the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` property.
- Each WCF service implementation retrieves the connection string from the `CustomPrincipal` in order to fetch data from the appropriate `ClientData` database.

My questions/thoughts are the following:

1. If I decide to use concurrency in my WCF services, how will I handle that due to the fact that `CheckAccessCore` is a method of a WCF extension that force concurrent operations to run sequentially?

   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/KbView/2907010

   This means that all my call will be enqueued and blocked at the `checkAccessCore` level.

   Overriding `checkAccessCore` is the best way I found to intercept calls early in the call stack in order to verify user credentials.
2. Should I use a different way to transport the client connection string other than over the custom identity? Is it secure?

If I use concurrency, I guess the identity set into the `CustomPrincipal` will be overridden. If yes, how to handle that?